# I want to disable Begin Form using page load function

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, iframe, pageload

In my aspx page I have BeginForm() which contains a table T1 and i also have an Iframe I1 which is not included  in Begin Form(). 
The problem that i m facing i have condition to check based on which i need to disable the table  T1 and enable the Ifram I1. 
For this, i m using the Page Load () function which helps me check the condition but i m unable to access the Table T1 and hence cant set its visible value to false. 
i dont mind adding javascript.

The code :
<%
        using (Html.BeginForm())
        {

```
%>
<table id="HomePage">
    <td>......

</table>

<%   for (int i = ViewData.Model.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     { %>
<div style="display: none;" id="hiddenView">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("PartiealView",object); %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
    {
        if (a == b)
        {
            enable Iframe I1 and disable table t1
        }
        else { enable Table T1 n disable Iframe 1 }


    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the: `runat="server"` attribute to your `table` and `iframe` elements you will have access to them in your code, they will be exposed as `HtmlControl` objects, which have a `Visible` property for you. (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khc6t495(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot.... i dont know how did i missed dat i shud have that image as my profile pic.. thanks a lot once again..

Answer (score 1):

Wrap an if-block around the items you wish to test:

```
<% if (...) { %>
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
<% } else { %>
    <iframe ...>
    </iframe>
<% } %>
```

Comment: this makes sense but the problem is value tha i want to check is in my class n i am unable to access that value without a page load function in c#.. <script type = "Text/C#">
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
 {
  if (a == b)
  {
   enable Iframe I1 and disable table t1
  }
  else { enable Table T1 n disable Iframe 1 }
   
  
 }
  
</script>